# How can I implement IBC token transfer from CosmosHub to my chain?

Tags: token, blockchain, cosmos

I am a smart contract developer using Rust and have experienced Cosmos blockchain.
IBC seems recent technology and wanna implement IBC token transfer from Cosmos Hub to my own Cosmos chain.
There should be a relayer but not sure where to start.
And also Cosmos docs does not give me proper instructions.

I used Ignite CLI tool to make a local chain but not sure if I should implement token transfer module(using ICS-20).

So my questions are below:

1. Should I implement token transfer module(using ICS-20) on my chain or is it implemented by default?
2. If I send atom to my chain, there is a denom(e.g ibc/F48DE...), how can I get denom name?
3. Clear instructions to install relayer.
   Which is better among TS relayer, Golang relayer and Hermes relayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved using IBC relayer like TypeScript Relayer(github.com/confio/ts-relayer), Go relayer or Hermes relayer.